# Optimize Java stack size

Tags: java

There are 20 threads running in the application at a time. I want to optimize the amount of memory allocated when creating a stack for each thread. To set a fixed amount of memory allocated for the stack, I wanted to use the -XX:ThreadStackSize flag.
How much is it advisable to optimize the amount of allocated memory?
Was it worth it?
Where do you recommend to start?

At the moment, 1 MB of memory is allocated for each stack

Comment: Are you in a particularly memory constrained environment? If you have twenty threads the maximum amount of memory you can save is 20MB, which is nothing compared to heap sizes on most JVMs. Can you explain why you are looking into this?

Comment: No, I'm not in an environment with a particularly limited amount of memory. My goal is not only to gain in memory, but also to gain a useful optimization experience.

Comment: Reduce it by successive halving until you start getting stack overflow exceptions, then you've gone too far. But 1MB is plenty for most applications. Java puts most memory into the heap, not the stack.

Comment: Thanks user207421. So far, this is the most popular advice that I have heard from my colleagues.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly useful optimisation experience. Depending on your environment, learning to use a profiler, learning to configure logging for timing DB queries (and other IO) and learning to read heap dumps are much more useful.

Comment: @kleopatra Wow, I had no idea. As someone who has both tried to use ChatGPT to answer tricky questions, and flagged a bunch of bad ChatGPT generated answers in the java tag, I'm shocked.

Comment: @Sergey just having the number of threads is not useful to make decisions on tuning. How did you even know that this particular setting is relevant to your objective? I can't even remember a situation when I had to use it. We don't know what your application does, how it is designed, what is the implementation, how threads are used, heap, native memory, stack, cpu usage patterns. This is a complex topic. Don't just jump to the first setting you see.